# JavaScript Arrays, Error in code

Tags: javascript, arrays

My task is to design an algorithm that will prompt for and receive an employee number from an operator at a terminal. My program is to search an array of valid employee numbers to check that the employee number is valid, look up a parallel array to retrieve the corresponding employee name for that number, and display the name to the screen. If the employee number is not valid, an error message is to be displayed.

```
var Emp_num  = new Array(123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,901,012);
var Emp_name = new
Array("ED","BOB","LOU","JEAN","MAX","SUE","VIC","TOM","CAL","MO");

var Req_num = prompt("Enter Employee Number: ");

var Emp_idx = Emp_num.indexOf(parseInt(Req_num, 10));

if (Emp_idx > -1) {
    alert("Employee name: " + Emp_name[Emp_idx]);
} else {
    alert("Employee number not found.");
}
```

I get an error message when i run this, and im just curious what im doing wrong?

(Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf')

Also, if theres another way to improve the code, tips are appreciated!!

Comment: Are you using IE8 or less?

Comment: I think `indexOf` isn't supported in all browsers.  Maybe you should loop through the array instead?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf Gives Polyfill and shows browser support.

Answer (score 1):

The `Array.indexOf` method only exist in some browsers. Loop through the items in the array to see if you find it.

Answer (score 0):

For browsers that *don't* support `indexOf` (such as IE8 or earlier), you can implement it yourself:

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
     for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
         if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
     }
     return -1;
}
```

[More Information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on `indexOf`

Comment: awesome! just curious though on how this code is working? like.. what exactly is it doing and how? -just for some personal knowledge (:

Comment: Basically, it's creating a function called `indexOf` that is a member of Array's *prototype*, thus it's available to any instance of an array.  Within the code, `this` refers to the array you're calling the function on.